# Matching numbers between curvy brackets

Tags: r, regex

```r
library(tidyverse)
```

I have this following string:

```r
str <- "1170\t{\r\n1170\t   860\r\n1170\t  5530\r\n1170\t   690\r\n1170\t  1200\r\n1170\t   390\r\n1170\t   740\r\n1170\t   350\r\n1170\t   490\r\n1170\t   360\r\n1170\t   440\r\n1170\t   450\r\n1170\t   580\r\n1170\t   620\r\n1170\t   740\r\n1300\t   730\r\n1300\t   870\r\n1300\t   800\r\n1300\t   850\r\n1300\t   810\r\n1300\t   870\r\n1300\t   830\r\n1300\t   860\r\n1300\t  1050\r\n1300\t   540\r\n1300\t   550\r\n1300\t   300\r\n1300\t   280\r\n1300\t   190\r\n1430\t   150\r\n1430\t    90\r\n1430\t    70\r\n1430\t    40\r\n1430\t   908\r\n1430\t  1238\r\n1430\t  3553\r\n1430\t   588\r\n1430\t    73\r\n1430\t 65480\r\n1430\t 19714\r\n1430\t  2756\r\n1430\t}"
```

What I would like to do is to extract the furst number (1170) and all other numbers before the **\r** (860, 5530, 690, 1200, …). So far I have this working:

```r
str_match(str, "(\\d+)\\t\\{\\s*([^.]*)\\t\\}")
#>      [,1]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
#> [1,] "1170\t{\r\n1170\t   860\r\n1170\t  5530\r\n1170\t   690\r\n1170\t  1200\r\n1170\t   390\r\n1170\t   740\r\n1170\t   350\r\n1170\t   490\r\n1170\t   360\r\n1170\t   440\r\n1170\t   450\r\n1170\t   580\r\n1170\t   620\r\n1170\t   740\r\n1300\t   730\r\n1300\t   870\r\n1300\t   800\r\n1300\t   850\r\n1300\t   810\r\n1300\t   870\r\n1300\t   830\r\n1300\t   860\r\n1300\t  1050\r\n1300\t   540\r\n1300\t   550\r\n1300\t   300\r\n1300\t   280\r\n1300\t   190\r\n1430\t   150\r\n1430\t    90\r\n1430\t    70\r\n1430\t    40\r\n1430\t   908\r\n1430\t  1238\r\n1430\t  3553\r\n1430\t   588\r\n1430\t    73\r\n1430\t 65480\r\n1430\t 19714\r\n1430\t  2756\r\n1430\t}"
#>      [,2]  
#> [1,] "1170"
#>      [,3]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
#> [1,] "1170\t   860\r\n1170\t  5530\r\n1170\t   690\r\n1170\t  1200\r\n1170\t   390\r\n1170\t   740\r\n1170\t   350\r\n1170\t   490\r\n1170\t   360\r\n1170\t   440\r\n1170\t   450\r\n1170\t   580\r\n1170\t   620\r\n1170\t   740\r\n1300\t   730\r\n1300\t   870\r\n1300\t   800\r\n1300\t   850\r\n1300\t   810\r\n1300\t   870\r\n1300\t   830\r\n1300\t   860\r\n1300\t  1050\r\n1300\t   540\r\n1300\t   550\r\n1300\t   300\r\n1300\t   280\r\n1300\t   190\r\n1430\t   150\r\n1430\t    90\r\n1430\t    70\r\n1430\t    40\r\n1430\t   908\r\n1430\t  1238\r\n1430\t  3553\r\n1430\t   588\r\n1430\t    73\r\n1430\t 65480\r\n1430\t 19714\r\n1430\t  2756\r\n1430"
```

Any help appreciated.
Phil
<sup>Created on 2018-12-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: If you need to extract strings and are already using `stringr`, you can use `str_extract`/`str_extract_all` instead

Comment: Could you please clarify: you want to extract any sequences of digits between ... and ....? Sorry, it is not quite clear now.

Comment: See [`(?:\G(?!^)|{)[^{}\d]*\K\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/ohKEQ6/1).

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

str <- "1170\t{\r\n1170\t   860\r\n1170\t  5530\r\n1170\t   690\r\n1170\t  1200\r\n1170\t   390\r\n1170\t   740\r\n1170\t   350\r\n1170\t   490\r\n1170\t   360\r\n1170\t   440\r\n1170\t   450\r\n1170\t   580\r\n1170\t   620\r\n1170\t   740\r\n1300\t   730\r\n1300\t   870\r\n1300\t   800\r\n1300\t   850\r\n1300\t   810\r\n1300\t   870\r\n1300\t   830\r\n1300\t   860\r\n1300\t  1050\r\n1300\t   540\r\n1300\t   550\r\n1300\t   300\r\n1300\t   280\r\n1300\t   190\r\n1430\t   150\r\n1430\t    90\r\n1430\t    70\r\n1430\t    40\r\n1430\t   908\r\n1430\t  1238\r\n1430\t  3553\r\n1430\t   588\r\n1430\t    73\r\n1430\t 65480\r\n1430\t 19714\r\n1430\t  2756\r\n1430\t}"
```

Few lines:

```
> str %>% writeLines()
1170    {
1170       860
1170      5530
1170       690
```

This code gives all numbers on the left:

```
str_match_all(str, "(\\d{1,})\\t") %>% 
  data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)  %>% 
  .$X2 %>% 
  as.numeric()
```